# Screen Flickering while installing ubuntu 16

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, nvidia, flicker

I have windows 10 installed.I want to dual boot it with ubuntu 16.04 which I am booting from usb, made bootable using gpt partition.But when I am trying to boot from the live cd(i.e the flash drive) it is showing [this(FLICKERING PROBLEM)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1EVjm6mQgE).Further my laptop also has nvidia video card.Most of the flickering problems which I have found on the internet were related to nvidia video cards but I don't know whether it is the problem or not.So how to fix this?